# How do I see that the complex ODE $z^{''} - 2iz = 0$ has a $2$-dimensional solution space?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I see that the complex ODE $z^{''} - 2iz = 0$ defined on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb C$ has a $2$-dimensional solution space ?

I've already found the family of solutions given by $\{ ae^{t+it} + be^{-t-it}\}$ for $a,b \in \mathbb C$. And I see that this space has dimension $2$. How do I know that the solution space has dimension $2$, so that I've found all solutions ?

Comment: Any IVP $z''-2i z=0$, $z(t_0)=z_0$, $z'(t_0)=w_0$ can be solved in terms of the solutions you have found.

Comment: What exactly does this imply ?

Comment: constant coefficient, linear second order differential equation has two linearly independent solutions. this is the basic existence theroem.

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic fact of the theory of ODEs that a linear differential equation
$$z''(t)+p(t) z'(t)+q(t) z(t)=0$$
with continuous real- or complex-valued coefficient functions
$$t\mapsto p(t), \quad t\mapsto q(t)\qquad(a<t<b)$$
has a two-dimensional vector space ${\cal L}$ of solutios $t\mapsto z(t)$, all of which live over the whole interval $\ ]a,b[\ $. Your ODE is a very special case of this: The coefficient functions $p$ and $q$ are constant, whence continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}$.

By whatever means you have found two solutions $\phi_\pm (t):=e^{\pm(1+i)t}$, which are defined on all of ${\mathbb R}$, and are linearly independent. It follows that ${\cal L}=\langle\phi_+,\phi_-\rangle$.